# How to create jolt spec for this complex JSON

Tags: java, jolt

I am learning JOLT and trying to write spce for the following use case. I can't seems to make the spec to convert the input JSON to desired format.

Here is my input.json

```
{
  "sourceTables": [
    {
      "sourceSchemaName": "vsc",
      "sourceTableName": "user",
      "sourceTableColumnDefinitions": [
        {
          "sourceColumnName": "userId",
          "sourceColumnAttributes": "",
          "sourceColumnType": "varchar"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sourceSchemaName": "npp",
      "sourceTableName": "profile",
      "sourceTableColumnDefinitions": [
        {
          "sourceColumnName": "profileId",
          "sourceColumnAttributes": "",
          "sourceColumnType": "int"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "targetTables": [
    {
      "targetSchemaName": "chr",
      "targetTableName": "userAccount",
      "targetTableColumnDefinitions": [
        {
          "sourceSchemaName": "vsc",
          "sourceTableName": "user",
          "sourceColumnName": "userId",
          "targetColumn": "id",
          "targetColumnAttributes": "",
          "targetColumnType": "varchar"
        },
        {
          "sourceSchemaName": "npp",
          "sourceTableName": "profile",
          "sourceColumnName": "profileId",
          "targetColumn": "pId",
          "targetColumnAttributes": "",
          "targetColumnType": "int"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "targetSchemaName": "chr",
      "targetTableName": "pIds",
      "targetTableColumnDefinitions": [
        {
          "sourceSchemaName": "npp",
          "sourceTableName": "profile",
          "sourceColumnName": "profileId",
          "targetColumn": "pId",
          "targetColumnAttributes": "",
          "targetColumnType": "int"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, my input.json has list of source table names along with column definitions for each and list of target table names and in targetTableColumnDefinitions array, the mapping information for column is available. Such as from which source table and column the current target column is mapped to.

Now, I want to convert this JSON as below

```
{
  "source": {
    "npp-profile": {
      "id": "npp-profile",
      "schemaName": "npp",
      "tableName": "profile",
      "mappedTargetTableNames": ["chr-pIds", "chr-userAccount"],
      "sourceColumnMap": {
        "profileId": {
          "sourceColumnDefinition": {
            "schemaName": "npp",
            "tableName": "profile",
            "columnName": "profileId",
            "columnType": "int",
            "columnAttributes": null
          },
          "mappedTargetColumnDefinition": [
            {
              "schemaName": "chr",
              "tableName": "userAccount",
              "columnName": "pId",
              "columnType": "int",
              "columnAttributes": null
            },
            {
              "schemaName": "chr",
              "tableName": "pIds",
              "columnName": "id",
              "columnType": "int",
              "columnAttributes": null
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "vsc-user": {
      "id": "vsc-user",
      "schemaName": "vsc",
      "tableName": "user",
      "mappedTargetTableNames": ["chr-userAccount"],
      "sourceColumnMap": {
        "userId": {
          "sourceColumnDefinition": {
            "schemaName": "vsc",
            "tableName": "user",
            "columnName": "userId",
            "columnType": "varchar",
            "columnAttributes": null
          },
          "mappedTargetColumnDefinition": [
            {
              "schemaName": "chr",
              "tableName": "userAccount",
              "columnName": "id",
              "columnType": "varchar",
              "columnAttributes": null
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "target": {
    "chr-pIds": {
      "id": "chr-pIds",
      "schemaName": "chr",
      "tableName": "pIds",
      "mappedSourceTables": ["npp-profile"],
      "targetColumnMap": {
        "id": {
          "targetColumnDefinition": {
            "schemaName": "chr",
            "tableName": "pIds",
            "columnName": "id",
            "columnType": "int",
            "columnAttributes": null
          },
          "mappedSourceColumnDefinition": {
            "schemaName": "npp",
            "tableName": "profile",
            "columnName": "profileId",
            "columnType": "int",
            "columnAttributes": null
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "chr-userAccount": {
      "id": "chr-userAccount",
      "schemaName": "chr",
      "tableName": "userAccount",
      "mappedSourceTables": ["npp-profile", "vsc-user"],
      "targetColumnMap": {
        "pId": {
          "targetColumnDefinition": {
            "schemaName": "chr",
            "tableName": "userAccount",
            "columnName": "pId",
            "columnType": "int",
            "columnAttributes": null
          },
          "mappedSourceColumnDefinition": {
            "schemaName": "npp",
            "tableName": "profile",
            "columnName": "profileId",
            "columnType": "int",
            "columnAttributes": null
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "targetColumnDefinition": {
            "schemaName": "chr",
            "tableName": "userAccount",
            "columnName": "id",
            "columnType": "varchar",
            "columnAttributes": null
          },
          "mappedSourceColumnDefinition": {
            "schemaName": "vsc",
            "tableName": "user",
            "columnName": "userId",
            "columnType": "varchar",
            "columnAttributes": null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to list all source tables under source object and all target tables under target object. I also want to create a new element called 'mappedTargetTableNames' in each source table object to find out which target table it is mapped to. Similarly, 'mappedSourceTables' needs to be added in each target table to find out which source tables are linked to the target table. And for each column in sourceTable object, I want to create the list of target table columns as one source table's column could map to multiple target table columns. Similarly I want to have source column details for each target table columns. Please can you help to write a jolt spec for this.
Please can you help to create the Jolt spec for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the transformation is a little bit complicated.  You may try another JSON library *Josson* to do the job.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"sourceTables\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"sourceSchemaName\": \"vsc\"," +
    "      \"sourceTableName\": \"user\"," +
    "      \"sourceTableColumnDefinitions\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "          \"sourceColumnName\": \"userId\"," +
    "          \"sourceColumnAttributes\": \"\"," +
    "          \"sourceColumnType\": \"varchar\"" +
    "        }" +
    "      ]" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"sourceSchemaName\": \"npp\"," +
    "      \"sourceTableName\": \"profile\"," +
    "      \"sourceTableColumnDefinitions\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "          \"sourceColumnName\": \"profileId\"," +
    "          \"sourceColumnAttributes\": \"\"," +
    "          \"sourceColumnType\": \"int\"" +
    "        }" +
    "      ]" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]," +
    "  \"targetTables\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"targetSchemaName\": \"chr\"," +
    "      \"targetTableName\": \"userAccount\"," +
    "      \"targetTableColumnDefinitions\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "          \"sourceSchemaName\": \"vsc\"," +
    "          \"sourceTableName\": \"user\"," +
    "          \"sourceColumnName\": \"userId\"," +
    "          \"targetColumn\": \"id\"," +
    "          \"targetColumnAttributes\": \"\"," +
    "          \"targetColumnType\": \"varchar\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "          \"sourceSchemaName\": \"npp\"," +
    "          \"sourceTableName\": \"profile\"," +
    "          \"sourceColumnName\": \"profileId\"," +
    "          \"targetColumn\": \"pId\"," +
    "          \"targetColumnAttributes\": \"\"," +
    "          \"targetColumnType\": \"int\"" +
    "        }" +
    "      ]" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"targetSchemaName\": \"chr\"," +
    "      \"targetTableName\": \"pIds\"," +
    "      \"targetTableColumnDefinitions\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "          \"sourceSchemaName\": \"npp\"," +
    "          \"sourceTableName\": \"profile\"," +
    "          \"sourceColumnName\": \"profileId\"," +
    "          \"targetColumn\": \"pId\"," +
    "          \"targetColumnAttributes\": \"\"," +
    "          \"targetColumnType\": \"int\"" +
    "        }" +
    "      ]" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");
```

**Transformation**

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(source:sourceTables@" +
    "    .let($srcSchema:sourceSchemaName)" +
    "    .let($srcTable:sourceTableName)" +
    "    .map(concat(sourceSchemaName,'-',sourceTableName)::map(" +
    "         id:concat(sourceSchemaName,'-',sourceTableName)," +
    "         schemaName:sourceSchemaName," +
    "         tableName:sourceTableName," +
    "         mappedTargetTableNames:$.targetTables[targetTableColumnDefinitions[sourceSchemaName=$srcSchema & sourceTableName=$srcTable]]*.concat(targetSchemaName,'-',targetTableName)," +
    "         sourceColumnMap:sourceTableColumnDefinitions" +
    "             .map(sourceColumnName::map(" +
    "                  sourceColumnDefinition:map(" +
    "                      schemaName:$srcSchema," +
    "                      tableName:$srcTable," +
    "                      columnName:sourceColumnName," +
    "                      columnType:sourceColumnType," +
    "                      columnAttributes:sourceColumnAttributes" +
    "                  )," +
    "                  mappedTargetColumnDefinition:$.targetTables@" +
    "                      .let($tgtSchema:targetSchemaName)" +
    "                      .let($tgtTable:targetTableName)" +
    "                      .targetTableColumnDefinitions[sourceSchemaName=$srcSchema & sourceTableName=$srcTable]*.map(" +
    "                          schemaName:$tgtSchema," +
    "                          tableName:$tgtTable," +
    "                          columnName:targetColumn," +
    "                          columnType:targetColumnType," +
    "                          columnAttributes:targetColumnAttributes" +
    "                      ).mergeObjects()" +
    "             )).mergeObjects()" +
    "    ))" +
    "    .@mergeObjects()," +
    "    " +
    "    target:targetTables@" +
    "    .let($tgtSchema:targetSchemaName)" +
    "    .let($tgtTable:targetTableName)" +
    "    .map(concat(targetSchemaName,'-',targetTableName)::map(" +
    "         id:concat(targetSchemaName,'-',targetTableName)," +
    "         schemaName:targetSchemaName," +
    "         tableName:targetTableName," +
    "         mappedSourceTables:targetTableColumnDefinitions.concat(sourceSchemaName,'-',sourceTableName)," +
    "         targetColumnMap:targetTableColumnDefinitions@" +
    "             .let($srcSchema:sourceSchemaName)" +
    "             .let($srcTable:sourceTableName)" +
    "             .let($srcColumn:sourceColumnName)" +
    "             .map(targetColumn::map(" +
    "                 targetColumnDefinition:map(" +
    "                     schemaName:$tgtSchema," +
    "                     tableName:$tgtTable," +
    "                     columnName:targetColumn," +
    "                     columnType:targetColumnType," +
    "                     columnAttributes:targetColumnAttributes" +
    "                 )," +
    "                 mappedSourceColumnDefinition:$.sourceTables[sourceSchemaName=$srcSchema & sourceTableName=$srcTable].sourceTableColumnDefinitions[sourceColumnName=$srcColumn].map(" +
    "                     schemaName:$srcSchema," +
    "                     tableName:$srcTable," +
    "                     columnName:$srcColumn," +
    "                     columnType:sourceColumnType," +
    "                     columnAttributes:sourceColumnAttributes" +
    "                 )" +
    "             ))" +
    "         .@mergeObjects()" +
    "    ))" +
    "    .@mergeObjects()" +
    ")");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "source" : {
    "vsc-user" : {
      "id" : "vsc-user",
      "schemaName" : "vsc",
      "tableName" : "user",
      "mappedTargetTableNames" : [ "chr-userAccount" ],
      "sourceColumnMap" : {
        "userId" : {
          "sourceColumnDefinition" : {
            "schemaName" : "vsc",
            "tableName" : "user",
            "columnName" : "userId",
            "columnType" : "varchar",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          },
          "mappedTargetColumnDefinition" : [ {
            "schemaName" : "chr",
            "tableName" : "userAccount",
            "columnName" : "id",
            "columnType" : "varchar",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          } ]
        }
      }
    },
    "npp-profile" : {
      "id" : "npp-profile",
      "schemaName" : "npp",
      "tableName" : "profile",
      "mappedTargetTableNames" : [ "chr-userAccount", "chr-pIds" ],
      "sourceColumnMap" : {
        "profileId" : {
          "sourceColumnDefinition" : {
            "schemaName" : "npp",
            "tableName" : "profile",
            "columnName" : "profileId",
            "columnType" : "int",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          },
          "mappedTargetColumnDefinition" : [ {
            "schemaName" : "chr",
            "tableName" : "userAccount",
            "columnName" : "pId",
            "columnType" : "int",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          }, {
            "schemaName" : "chr",
            "tableName" : "pIds",
            "columnName" : "pId",
            "columnType" : "int",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "target" : {
    "chr-userAccount" : {
      "id" : "chr-userAccount",
      "schemaName" : "chr",
      "tableName" : "userAccount",
      "mappedSourceTables" : [ "vsc-user", "npp-profile" ],
      "targetColumnMap" : {
        "id" : {
          "targetColumnDefinition" : {
            "schemaName" : "chr",
            "tableName" : "userAccount",
            "columnName" : "id",
            "columnType" : "varchar",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          },
          "mappedSourceColumnDefinition" : {
            "schemaName" : "vsc",
            "tableName" : "user",
            "columnName" : "userId",
            "columnType" : "varchar",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          }
        },
        "pId" : {
          "targetColumnDefinition" : {
            "schemaName" : "chr",
            "tableName" : "userAccount",
            "columnName" : "pId",
            "columnType" : "int",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          },
          "mappedSourceColumnDefinition" : {
            "schemaName" : "npp",
            "tableName" : "profile",
            "columnName" : "profileId",
            "columnType" : "int",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "chr-pIds" : {
      "id" : "chr-pIds",
      "schemaName" : "chr",
      "tableName" : "pIds",
      "mappedSourceTables" : [ "npp-profile" ],
      "targetColumnMap" : {
        "pId" : {
          "targetColumnDefinition" : {
            "schemaName" : "chr",
            "tableName" : "pIds",
            "columnName" : "pId",
            "columnType" : "int",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          },
          "mappedSourceColumnDefinition" : {
            "schemaName" : "npp",
            "tableName" : "profile",
            "columnName" : "profileId",
            "columnType" : "int",
            "columnAttributes" : ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```